# Nested for loop 2D array initialization not working (java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

i'm trying to simply create a method that returns a 2D array that has all the values entered based off a given pattern. Eclipse says that my code doesn't have any errors, yet when I go to run I get the response "[[I@2a139a55". I googled it and learned what it was about, yet I still don't know how to fix my code.

```
public class Transpose {

public static int[][] createPatterned2DArray(int row,int column){
    int width = column;
    int height = row;
    int[][] array = new int[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = i + j + (width * i);
        }
    }

    return array;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.print(createPatterned2DArray(3,5));


}

}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.deepToString`

Comment: the output is correct, as an `array` is an `Object`. Here it uses the default `Object` implementation of `toString`, which is printing the `type@hascode ` of the `Object`. You either want to iterate over it or use some api to print it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

or if your array contains other arrays as elements

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array))
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to print the 2d array.

For that you cannot simply do `System.out.println()`

The code should be somewhat like the following:

```
public class Transpose {

    public static int[][] createPatterned2DArray(int row,int column){
        int width = column;
        int height = row;
        int[][] array = new int[height][width];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = i + j + (width * i);

            }
        }

        return array;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int arr[][] = createPatterned2DArray(3,5);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `System.out.print(array)` statement won't give you the expected output of array elements values:

Actually you will get like this strange output when you print the array:

```
[[I@15db9742
```

The reason for this output:

> An array is treated as an object, so the default outcome of
>   `Object#toString()` will be used as string representation.

To achieve what you want:

- Use `Arrays.toString()` method to print simple array or one-dimensional array.
- Use `Arrays.deepToString()`method to print nested array.
- Or you can use for loop traditional way to print the array.

In your case to print the 2D array you can just use:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(createPatterned2DArray(3,5)));
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/5169186) for more information.